# How do I make Vim use a default filename when not given any filenames?

Tags: vimrc, startup

I rarely, if ever, just open `vim` without filenames. Often enough, I want to test something out, usually a quick throwaway script, and I usually name them `test.sh` (or some variant thereof, like `test.py`). Can I make `vim` assume a `test.sh` filename if I ran `vim` without any filenames? I'd usually use aliases (like `vims` for `vim test.sh` and `vimp` for `vim test.py`, or go the whole `:w test.sh`), but I wonder if there's a way from within `vim`. It would be even better if I can restrict this to certain directories, like `/tmp`, or `~/dev`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try putting this at the end of your .vimrc (modify as appropriate)

```
if @% == "" && getcwd() == "/tmp"
    :silent edit test.sh
endif
```

This checks if the current filename is empty (`@%` references the current filename), and checks if vim's current directory is `/tmp`. You could add other directories as well like so

```
(getcwd() == "/tmp" || getcwd() == "~/dev")
```

It then silently edits test.sh. If that file already exists, it'll load it. Otherwise, you'll start a new buffer with that name and the file will be created if you write it.

I did silent to suppress the following message during startup:

```
"test.sh" [New File]
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 5):

A modification of John's answer may be useful:

```
if @% == "" && getcwd() == "/tmp"
    :silent edit `=glob("test\.*", 1, 1)[0]`
endif
```

That opens the first file which begins with `test.`.

Instead of just the first file, if you wanted to open other matching files as well, do:

```
if @% == "" && getcwd() == "/tmp"
    for i in glob("test\.*", 1, 1)
        :silent edit `=i`
    endfor
endif
```