# Defining mappings for files of the "null" type through /ftplugin

Tags: vimrc, gvim, vim-windows, macvim

For files of a certain `filetype`, specifying "file-type-specific" mappings is simple.

- If Vim opens a fill and return `filetype=python` after issuing command `:set filetype?` through command-line (native to Vim), then python-specific mappings could be defined directly through `~/ftplugin/python.vim`;
- However, where shall I specify the mappings for files that return `filetype=` after issuing command `:set filetype?`. This applies to cases where one does not give a file any extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luc said, you would have to use an `autocmd`:

```
augroup NoFileType
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if &filetype ==# '' | setlocal filetype=noft | endif
  autocmd FileType noft echom 'No file type!'
augroup END
```

Or just add this to `ftdetect/noft.vim`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if &filetype ==# '' | set filetype=noft | endif
```

Then you can add mappings in `ftplugin/noft.vim`.

Also see [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/how-can-i-run-an-autocmd-when-starting-vim-with-no-file-a-non-existing-file-or) about detecting an empty file at startup.

Comment: Instead of adding the one-liner to `ftdetect/noft.vim`, I dropped it directly to a `*.vim` file that is sourced when my Vim starts. Then, as you have described, dropping arbitrary settings into the `ftplugin/noft.vim` shall work for "headless" files.

Comment: You might want wrap your auto commands with in at least one `augroup`: executing `autocmd!` clears the current group, otherwise a new autocmd copy is created each time the file is sourced. You can inspect a group with `:verbose au GroupName`. See [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9459/12003) and `:h 40.3` for more details. Using `ftdetect/*.vim` takes care of the autocmd namespacing.

Answer (score 1):

An `autocmd` is not necessarly needed. Using `<expr>`, a check on `filetype` can do it too:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Leader>M &filetype == '' ? ":echo 'Example'<CR>" : ""
```

With `:h <expr>`, the mapping is set to the result of the expression on the right-hand side.

Here, if `&filetype` is empty, it will be set to `:echo 'Example'<cr>`. Else, it will be set to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a autocommand for all buffers that'd test for the filetype. I'm afraid there is no other way.

Comment: OH, is it a function that may return a binary outcome variable after comparing the return value of `:set filetype?` against an empty string? I am afraid I don't know Vim script well enough to construct such function/autocommand on top of my head.

Comment: In the autocommand you could indeed write something like `if empty (&ft) | runtime ftplugin/nofiletype/*.vim | endif` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case for such feature, if you just don't want to have that mapping in files with a type, then you can set normal mapping and autocommand for any filetype that will remove that mapping:

```
nnoremap <Leader>M :echo "Example"<CR>

autocmd FileType * :nnoremap <buffer> <Leader>M <NOP>
```

This can have side effects if you would like to reuse that mapping in a file with a type - I'm not sure if it will work then (race condintion)

Comment: That will actually change whatever filetype was set to `notype` - rather not something that one would like to do.