# Setting a default file extension

Tags: command-line

Can I tell vim to assume a filename ends in `.tex` if no extension is given? e.g. to open bird.tex if I say `:e bird` (unless there is a file bird with no extension).

Comment: Related: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/239/205 - you can probably adapt one of those to use a check for extensions (or lack thereof) instead of checking the directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapting tricks I got from two of my previous questions, this should work:

```
function! EditTex(name)
    if a:name !~ '\.[^/]*$'
        setlocal bufhidden=wipe
        exe 'e' fnameescape(a:name).'.tex'
        set bufhidden<
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile * nested call EditTex(expand('<afile>'))
```

The function checks if the filename has an extension, and if not, starts editing a TeX file with that name. Since a `BufNewFile` `autocmd` will only run for files that don't exist, we can avoid that check.

With this, you can run `:e bird` as you normally would.

Sources:

- [How do I make vim look in a set of directories for a file, if it doesn't exist in the current directory?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2009/205)
- [How do I make Vim use a default filename when not given any filenames?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/239/205)

Comment: There is a problem with this, it creates `bird.tex` if you typ `vi bird` at the cmdline.

Comment: @Lawrence Is that a problem? I would have thought that expected behaviour.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my q. wasn't quite clear.  I wanted to open `bird.tex` unless `bird` existed, but not create a texfile when neither `bird` nor `bird.tex` existed from before.  When I think about it, maybe this was just a bad idea: I also want to be able to create `bird` even though `bird,tex` exists. Sorry!

Comment: @Lawrence then it is a bad idea, since you want to do both A and not A.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try the following custom command `:E` :

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=file E
            \ let s:file = fnamemodify('<args>', ':p') |
            \ if fnamemodify(s:file, ':e') ==# '' && !filereadable(s:file) |
            \     edit <args>.tex |
            \ else |
            \     edit <args> |
            \ endif |
            \ unlet s:file
```

It checks if the filename given as an argument has no extension if it doesn't exist. In this case, it executes `:edit {argument}.tex`, otherwise it executes `:edit {argument}`.

So if you type: `:E bird` it should load a buffer whose name is `bird.tex` unless a file named `bird` already exists.